# Regex quantifier with capturing group issue

Tags: java, regex, quantifiers, capturing-group

whats up?

I'm trying to get some regex to work, but I'm facing some "weird" (?) behaviour.

I need a regex that validates the following:

- Only numbers (no whitespaces at all)
- Starts with 10 or 11
- Must be 12 characters

After working for a while on this I'm stuck with this:

```
^(10|11)[0-9]{10}$
```

It seems to be working as desired, but I'm not satisfied since it's misleading at first glance. Must be 12 max characters but it validates max 10 + the 'starts with' characters.

Anyone have a better solution or care to explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance (:

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem if it works as desired... you don't like how the regex string looks..?

Comment: It's not that i don't like it, but have a 10 characters long validation where it actually validates 12, is misleading when doing maintenance to the code.

Comment: If you have an _eye_ problem, use this `^(?=(10|11))[0-9]{12}$`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about aesthetic appearance of code.

Answer (score 1):

Its not working as desired.
`{10}` means exactly 10 digits in your case.
You can use `{0,10}` which `Matches between 0 and 10 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed`

As for the misleading part - its subjective, if the number must start with either 10 or 11 so it must be 2 digits long and you can allow for not more than another 10 digits

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Sorry the error on the max characters, that's my bad :P

Actually it should be "Must be 12 characters long"

So, this behaviour for the quantifier is normal?

Comment: Yes, I believe you wanted to see something like "starts with 10 or 11 and is 12 digits long" and not seeing "12" in the regex made you uncomfortable, if it's the case you can use the one @sln proposed

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the following:

```
^(10|11)[0-9]{0,10}$
```

this means that it start with 10 or 11 and can have between 2 and 12 characters in length

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/t6usoZ/1)